# haproxy header rewrite to lower case

Tags: haproxy, http-headers

I have a custom app behind an haproxy server. Can haproxy rewrite the case of the header?

For example changing `http://www.company.com/ABC` to `http://www.company.com/abc`

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this easily enough:

```
reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /ABC(.*)     \1\ /abc\2
```

However, it is usually more appropriate to handle URL rewrites on the web server (e.g. mod_rewrite), so I would use these type of rewrites sparingly.

Comment: What if I don't know what the string will be?  Is it still possible to do the replace?

Comment: For example, I can't predict if it will be company.com/TEST, company.com/ABC, company.com/DOG, company.com/WHAT/EVER.

Comment: As far as I know, HAProxy *cannot* transform URLs using a function like that. You'll likely find it easier using rewrite rules in IIS or Apache to solve this issue.